# Failed to bounce to type

Tags: android, firebase

I have a database from which i want to select a specific node. For example in my case i want to select the nodes that username is "fatma". So how can i do that in android ?
 [image]

public  class User {

public  String username,email,password,dateOfBirth,signUpDate;

```
public User(String username, String email, String password,String dateOfBirth,String signUpDate) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.dateOfBirth=dateOfBirth;
    this.signUpDate=signUpDate;
}
public User(){

}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

public String getSignUpDate() {
    return signUpDate;
}

public void setSignUpDate(String signUpDate) {
    this.signUpDate = signUpDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "username='" + username + '\'' +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", password='" + password + '\'' +
            ", dateOfBirth='" + dateOfBirth + '\'' +
            ", signUpDate='" + signUpDate + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
Firebase.setAndroidContext(getApplicationContext());
            final Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/");
           /* String username,password;
            username=txtUsername.getText().toString();
            password=txtPassword.getText().toString();
            User authentificatedUser=new User(username,password,null,null,null);
            ConnectTask connectTask=new ConnectTask(authentificatedUser);
     txtUsername.setText(connectTask.getTest());*/

            Query query = ref.orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                    txtUsername.setText(user.getUsername());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

                }

            });
```

06-15 13:50:59.067 7510-7510/com.sifast.appsocle E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: com.sifast.appsocle, PID: 7510
                                                                   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                       at com.sifast.appsocle.Login$2$1.onDataChange(Login.java:71)
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:158)
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45)
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45)
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                    Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "-KKJOx4bBAgpJ3UPD-0a" (class com.sifast.appsocle.user.User), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: , "signUpDate", "username", "dateOfBirth", "password", "email"])
                                                                       at [Source: java.io.StringReader@c6fea0d; line: 1, column: 26] (through reference chain: com.sifast.appsocle.user.User["-KKJOx4bBAgpJ3UPD-0a"])
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:555)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:708)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1160)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:315)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
                                                                       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:181)
                                                                       at com.sifast.appsocle.Login$2$1.onDataChange(Login.java:71) 
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.Query$1.onDataChange(Query.java:158) 
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:45) 
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:45) 
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:38) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: The complete logcat error would be usefull, but I can say that `Failed to bounce to type` means that a field's type in the database doesn't match the corresponding variable type in your object

Comment: PID: 7510
                                                                   com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
                                                                       at com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:183)
                                                                       at com.sifast.appsocle.Login$2$1.onDataChange(Login.java:71)

Comment: I would need all of it. You can edit your question to add it.

Comment: i  edited the post

Comment: So, as you can see, you're trying to create object User with "-KKJOx4bBAgpJ3UPD-0a" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to users node, this should solve the problem. 
By this reference (https://app.firebaseio.com/) you're downloading all data, which results an error Failed to bounce to a type. 
@fatma19
You should use this reference: https://app.firebaseio.com/users .
Ok, if we have correct reference, we can start query data. 
Again,

```
Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://app.firebaseio.com/users");
Query query = firebase.orderByChild("username").equalTo("testme");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        //if u have unique usernames
        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
        //if u haven't unique usernames
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = snapshot.getChildren();
                List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshots){
                    users(dataSnapshot1.getValue(User));
                }
        //or
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
             users.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you write what data are coming to you in dataSnapshot?

Comment: User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);

Comment: i changed it but always the same

Comment: that's not what I meant. Use logcat (Log.e(TAG, dataSnapshot.toString());) :)

Comment: i made some changments in your code and it works :) thx a lot :)

Comment: @fatma19 I'm glad I could help :)  If you just started with firebase, I suggest you to use new firebase api, here's a link https://firebase.google.com :)

Answer (score 3):

Your Firebase reference is wrong.

```
Unrecognized field "-KKJOx4bBAgpJ3UPD-0a"
```

That means that you are in the node `user` and you are trying to convert `-KKJOx4bBAgpJ3UPD-0a` to a field in `User`. I am guessing you have/will have more than one `User`. So you probably want to parse the snapshot's children one by one with:

```
for(DataSnapshot user : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    User myUser = user.getValue(User.class);
}
```

Comment: @fatma19 post here your reference to users node

Comment: @fatma19 exclamation marks are not helpful. If you're still getting the same problem after making this change, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37838513/edit) to include the updated code.

Comment: @TheSunshinator he's querying by child equal to specified name. If he has only one user with that name, query will return only one user :)

Comment: I assumed he might not know the UID. Of course if he has it and only need that user, he can fetch it directly.